# AVD restart when sending location

Tags: android-emulator, gps, reboot

My android virtual device reboot when sending location to GPS. I have tried with DDMS location control and the telnet way

telnet localhost 5554
geo fix -77.036519 38.896143

but with the same result. Everyting else works an I can fx. send sms to it but sending a location and it reboot.

I am running windows server 2008 r2 interprice 64bit

Answer (score 3):

For Your Interest:
[Emulator crashes after attempting to send fake location fix via DDMS](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015)